# Processing Calculations With TemplateTag Returns None

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model **Coper** and a field that ask user to select whether they need to get price quotes dynamically or not. So if a user selects 'dynamic', the user will get the quote for the product and other charges.

So I wrote a template tag that will take the id of the product, filter the currency of the seller and lookup for the rate in another model and finish up the quote.

```
@register.filter(name='get_total_quote')
def get_total_quote(value):
    tap = Coper.objects.get(pk=value)
    get_cnd = VAM.objects.get(money_code = tap.seller.profile.currency)
    ratex = get_cnd.money_rate
    if tap.margin_type == 'plus':
        percent = tap.margin_figure / 100
        addup =  ratex * percent
        total_amt = ratex + addup
        return total_amt
    if tap.margin_type == 'minus':
        percent = tap.margin_figure / 100
        addup =  ratex * percent
        total_namt = ratex - addup
        return total_namt
```

Template

```
{% load quote_filter %}
    {% for m in all_quotes %}
        {% if m.pricing == 'dynamic' %}
            {{m.id|get_total_quote }}
        {% else %}
           <p> Fixed price is $3500 </p>
        {% endif %}
    {% empty %}
       <p> No product yet. </p>
     {% endfor %}
```

When I load the site, I got **NONE** as the price of the dynamic quote instead of the actual figure.

What am I missing?

Comment: Add some printing or logging to your template tag. Note that the template tag will return `None` if `margin_type` is neither `'plus'` nor `'minus'`.

Comment: Also, why are you passing just the ID to the tag and then querying Coper? Isn't `m` already a Coper object?

Comment: @Alasdair yes you are right. I don't know how I missed this! Now working fine! Thanks. Post it as answer to mark you up.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes I'm only passing the id of the product to the tag to work it. m is a Coper object, and I don't know of anyway to pass the value to the tag asides from doing that. If you have any suggestion like a better way of implementing this, kindly let me know.

Comment: Why not just `{{ m|get_total_quote }}`, then the value in the tag function is already the Coper object.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I got int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Coper' error.

Comment: Are you still trying to do `Coper.objects.get...` within the tag?

Comment: @DanielRoseman yeah in the filter file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If neither if statement is True, your tag returns `None`.

```
if tap.margin_type == 'plus':
    ...
    return total_amt
if tap.margin_type == 'minus':
    ...
    return total_amt
# if code gets to this point, you are implicitly returning None
```

As Daniel suggested in the Comments, you can pass the `Coper` object directly to the tag:

```
{{m|get_total_quote }}
```

then change the filter to accept `tap` and remove `tap = Coper.objects.get(pk=value)`:

```
@register.filter(name='get_total_quote')
def get_total_quote(tap):
    get_cnd = VAM.objects.get(money_code = tap.seller.profile.currency)
    ...
```